# Unable to use Cache Sink with Derived Column Transformation in Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to use a derived column transformation before writing it to a Cached Sink, But it gives me the following error: Function 'outputs' applies to only sink transformation with right saveOrder.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the sink order is set to 1 for your cached sink

[image]

Comment: @qudsif remember to mark this as correct, if this worked for you. I had the same problem, and it worked for me.